# Storing hierarchical data in MySQL with high write load

Tags: mysql, tree, hierarchy, hierarchical

I am building web application that should have high write load and thousands, even millions of hierarchical records representing user defined/constructed trees. I am not trying to build forum with threads but huge database with thousands of small-sized hierarchies (trees with up to 10-20 descendants)...

I am aware of many models for storing hierarchies - currently I am using Nested Sets but performance with huge data and load is issue. I am also doubtful that Adjacency Lists or something similar may resolve this.

I have been experimenting with Mongo database which is superfast key/value storage but I can use only MySQL.

I would like to hear about other people experiences with similar issues.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? You want to store all this and query the hierarchies? How are you going to do your queries?

Answer (score 5):

If you can install MySQL plugins, then [OQGraph](http://openquery.com/blog/tag/oqgraph) storage engine is what you need.

Comment: +1 However installing a plugin is not open to everybody. That's why I've awarded the bounty to @barryhunter

Comment: Thanks anyway ;) Remember, the more people know about OQGraph, the sooner we might see it as part of default installations at hosting companies :)

Answer (score 4):

What is the problem with nested sets?

Is recomputing the lft/rgt values when you add/remove nodes?

Pretty sure with a bit of careful planning, you can tweak it so do only have to do rare recomputations. I've not actully tried it, but did do some planning for a system once (the client didnt want the system in the end!)

One, is multiplying the values, by say 1000, when first calculating them. Then if you add a node, you can just insert numbers between the values. Its only when there is a large number of insertions, do you start running out of numbers. A low priority batch process, could recompute the tree to free up numbers for fresh insertions.

Deleting can also be archived, with manipulating numbers. In fact a node without children is easy. No recomputation nedded. Gets more complicated if children, but I think should be doable.

Comment: +1 Joe Celko has some great posts on this somewhere. I believe his book "Joe Celko's SQL for smarties" has a section on it also. Certainly worth a Google search.